# Vim actions like "da" that don't remove whitespace

Tags: vim

I have some text like this:

```
foo<space><space><space>'bar'
```

When I do `da'` inside `'bar'`, the whitespace is removed:

```
foo
```

How can I do `da'` without removing whitespace, so I get this as the result?

```
foo<space><space><space>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this in vim's help topic on `text-objects`:

```
i"                          *v_iquote* *iquote*
i'                          *v_i'* *i'*
i`                          *v_i`* *i`*
            Like a", a' and a`, but exclude the quotes and
            repeating won't extend the Visual selection.
            Special case: With a count of 2 the quotes are
            included, but no extra white space as with a"/a'/a`.
```

Thus, doing the below would not delete the whitespace.

```
d2i'
```

For more help on text objects, do `:help text-objects`

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in `:help v_i'`:

> For the "a" commands: The operator applies to the object and the white
>     space after the object.  If there is no white space after the object
>     or when the cursor was in the white space before the object, the white
>     space before the object is included.

So, the problem is that you're at the end of the line. To change the behavior, you can add a whitespace, go back, and then issue the command: `A<Space><Esc>hda'`.

Alternatively, use the *inner* object, and remove the two quotes afterwards, as in `di'hxx`.

For the quote text objects, there's even a handy special case, so **`d2i'` looks like the winner** here:

> ```
>   Special case: With a count of 2 the quotes are
>   included, but no extra white space as with a"/a'/a`.
> ```